# Material UI arrow when small device

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tabs, material-ui, media-queries

I am coding a tab bar but I've noticed that my tab bar doesn't show an indicator arrow button () when it reaches below 600px width.

I want to do like this:
[image: w]

But it shows like this  when its below 600px:

[image: s]

Anyone can help me how to add this arrow indicator when it reaches below 600px width?

Here's my code:

```
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Tabs from '@material-ui/core/Tabs';
import Tab from '@material-ui/core/Tab';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const StyledTabs = withStyles({
  indicator: {
    display: 'flex',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
    '& > span': {
      maxWidth: 80,
      width: '100%',
      backgroundColor: 'black',
    },
  },
})((props) => <Tabs {...props} TabIndicatorProps={{ children: <span /> }} />);

const StyledTab = withStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    textTransform: 'none',
    color: '#000',
    fontWeight: theme.typography.fontWeightRegular,
    fontSize: theme.typography.pxToRem(18),
    '&:focus': {
      opacity: 1,
    },
  },
}))((props) => <Tab disableRipple {...props} />);

const GalleryPage = () => {
  const [filterEvent, setFilterEvent] = React.useState('All');

  const handleChangeEvent = (event, newEvent) => {
    setFilterEvent(newEvent);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container justify="center" alignItems="flex-start">
        <StyledTabs variant="scrollable" value={filterEvent} onChange={handleChangeEvent} aria-label="styled tabs example">
          <StyledTab label="AAAAAA" value="All" />
          <StyledTab label="BBBBBB" value="Hiking" />
          <StyledTab label="CCCCCC" value="J-On" />
          <StyledTab label="DDDDDD" value="Language Exchange" />
          <StyledTab label="FFFFFF" value="Picnic" />
          <StyledTab label="HHHHHH" value="Random" />
          <StyledTab label="TTTTTT" value="Takusai" />
        </StyledTabs>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
};

export default GalleryPage;
```

Comment: If you copy your image and paste it in the editor it will actually embed your image instead of needing to link to it.

Comment: I know but I need to have at least 10 reputation to be able to pase the image

Comment: Ty now =) It should let you.

Answer (score 0):

In [MUI](https://mui.com/) version (5.11.8), By default, left and right scroll buttons are automatically presented on desktop and hidden on mobile. (based on viewport width).

You can use `Forced scroll buttons` i.e adding `scrollButtons={true}` and  `allowScrollButtonsMobile` attributes to your Tabs component, so that Left and right scroll buttons be presented regardless of the viewport width.

Check out this code snippet:

```
  import * as React from 'react';
  import Tabs from '@mui/material/Tabs';
  import Tab from '@mui/material/Tab';
  import Box from '@mui/material/Box';

  export default function ScrollableTabsButtonForce() {
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    const handleChange = (event: React.SyntheticEvent, newValue: number) => {
      setValue(newValue);
    };

    return (
      <Box sx={{ maxWidth: { xs: 320, sm: 480 }, bgcolor: 'background.paper' }}>
        <Tabs
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          variant="scrollable"
          scrollButtons
          allowScrollButtonsMobile
          aria-label="scrollable force tabs example"
        >
          <Tab label="Item One" />
          <Tab label="Item Two" />
          <Tab label="Item Three" />
          <Tab label="Item Four" />
          <Tab label="Item Five" />
          <Tab label="Item Six" />
          <Tab label="Item Seven" />
        </Tabs>
      </Box>
    );
  }
```